# Installation Confluent on Ubuntu is not working

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to install latest Confluent 4.1.x on Ubuntu 16.04.3 TLS on my Windows 7 through Oracle Tool box.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install confluent-platform-oss-2.11
```

Got notice while installation:

```
Notice: Not creating existing directory /var/log/confluent, 
ensure proper permissions for user cp-kafka group confluent
```

Above notice is came for all packages.

```
confluent start 
failed to start zookeeper, kafka
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Resolved. Jdk install missing. Its not showing the error.

Comment: You should be using something like `systemctl start confluent-kafka` if installing from apt